Practicallity Check of Floating Fish Enclosure
Introduction
I would like to start off by saying these are normal fish. The fish are just fish. The fish are not genetically engineered with the exception of say a GloTetra. The fish can be fresh or salt water which I don't imagine would change a lot but I only have experience with fresh water. If you know about salt water please do tell me!
Tabitha is a witch. Like all witches she has decided to enchant her home to be extra cool. Tabitha in this case likes fish and so has enchanted streams of water and bubbles of water to float around her house in set patterns. This means she can be on a zoom call in her library and have something float past just merrily swimming around. Tabitha also has a couple of 'waterfall' windows that lead into a small pool. These small pools have lotuses growing in them and which all of the water will eventually move to it and then leave to go float around. Ideally, Tabitha would be able do water tests and changes from these pools instead of having to hunt down every bubble individually. The only magic happening is the movement of the water!
In practice this would work very similarly to channels following the same path for the streams and for the bubbles to be similar to carrying a bowl with a fish and putting it back in. The upside is that due to ~magic~ it's less of a logistical nightmare to put a fish tunnel on your ceiling. For our purposes, the rule of cool/magic only provides us with a structure. Everything else is still a very real concern as otherwise Tabitha's fish will die.
Concerns
Temperature
The water would be room temperature in an temperature enclosed environment (the house). While this limits the amount of fish that can be kept it also means that there shouldn't be temperature fluctuations. The pools can be kept heated if that helps but the floating water cannot be.
Filtration
As far as I'm aware, the only way things could be filtered is through the set pools. These would then be sent off and eventually returned. I imagine since the continuous loops of water floating and leaving would keep the levels of nitrates, pH, and the like about the same in each one. These are caused mostly by fish poop and would do the same.
Light
This doesn't change even with Tabitha's fancy setup. Tabitha has the lights scheduled to turn on and off at set times. The plant's growth lights are disguised as properly witchy 'candles' and other witch like decor that Tabitha thinks is neat.
Fish don't want to take the floating fish metro/Feeding
I believe that if Tabitha slowly worked them into it while only feeding them in say the floating bubbles then the fish would do it. I mean if you can train a gold fish to play soccer and a betta fish to 'cuddle' then I don't see why you can't do the rest.
Air and Water Interactions/Fish jumping
So, I believe that the water from the 'waterfall windows' would be enough air but an air pump can be added to the pools if needed. The bubbles and streams would be enclosed entirely which means that the fish would have to rely entirely on the air that was already inside.
The streams are moving which would prevent a buildup of carbon dioxide which is a common problem in most fish tunnels. The bubbles would also be moving about five to ten minutes before heading back to remerge with a pool of water. I don't know if this is enough time but we can also say that the bubbles and stream include about an inch of air on the top which would help.
Sick Fish
Sick fish go to Tabitha's secret normal fish tanks that she keeps out of view because they aren't witchy. It's also where she keeps the things like egg boxes, spare air tubes, old credit cards to scrape things with, her fish food and other such fish things.
Summarized Question
So, Tabitha's (by which I mean me) designed her sometimes floating fish tanks with 'touchdown' pools. When Tabitha runs her fish enclosures will her fish drop dead? If so which aspect of the fish enclosure is killing them? Bonus points (in my heart if nothing else) if you suggest some fish species and if you can confirm/deny that this would work for salt water as well.
Edit 1: To clarify and narrow down question
Edit 2: Add some clarification on the bubbles/stream after some awesome questions by KerrAvon2055
Edit 3: Added fish poop by name instead of implication. Refined the air/water interactions

Pick one between science based and internal consistency: they are mutually exclusive

Does this work? I removed internal consistency and added water

You're asking an open ended question querying us for feedback. Is there a particular problem you're having that you would like help with? Try editing your post to ask about that, and only that.

Is there any practical difference between this set of magical floating streams of water and non-magical water flowing through non-magical perspex or glass channels following the same path?  Or, for the "bubbles", having some of the water flow into perspex bowls that are then carried around before being decanted back into the pool?  Any difference other than "rule of cool" and saving on perspex, that is?  (Depending on whether the streams are wide enough to for the fish to turn around, I'm reminded of the fishpond designed by Bloody Stupid Johnson in the Patrician's grounds in Ankh-Morpork.)

@sphennings Thanks, I fixed it be narrow now.

@KerrAvon2055 No, yeah, that's pretty much exactly how I imagine it would work. The only other difference then rule of cool would be not having to clean said perspex and that this would be automated. Like a fish elevator. I'm now looking into the example you listed!

The only problem I see is that you've not defined the nature of the magic constraining the water. I doubt Tabitha wants to deal with splashed water or dying fish lying about her home and it would be much simpler to define the magic streams like pipes (the magic is the equivalent of Star Trek's transparent aluminum and wholly encloses the water) and the pools like old fashioned aquariums. Thus, anything you can do in an aquarium or pipe you can do via Tabitha's magic. BTW, please note that we do not yet have a "review my idea" policy, so that kind of question doesn't work well here.

One more thing... using the [tag:science-based] tag for a circumstance that exists only because of [tag:magic] is a tall order.

@JBH I thought the science-based tag would be appropriate because it's the science that matters and the magic is just background details. Would magic be a better tag?

Is the magic stopping gas-exchange across the air-water interface? That's why we need to know about the magic. Is it allowing evaporation of any of the water? Does gravity still apply in height-differences? What happens to the fish waste? Could you tell us (in clear terms) about what exactly the magic does.

I think it would be. Science and magic mix poorly. The explanation of what your magic needs to do might sound sciency (like my comment's reference to pipes and aquariums), but no answer can be restricted to science or there isn't an answer. Take a moment to read that tag's wiki. It and its compatriots scope the answers, not the question.

@JBH After rereading the tags, I'm pretty certain that I want it to be science-based. Especially the answer. Thanks for asking!

@Escapeddentalpatient. What does gravity still applying mean at height differences? I'm pretty sure gravity would be the same if you are within the confines of a house. I have add the fish poop to the filtration section by name. I went through and refined the air-water interface details as well. Thanks for asking!

By asking about gravity, I meant there would effectively be a column of water the height of the house, with corresponding pressure differences. But the details seem clear-enough now after the edit, thanks.

If I'm understanding correctly, one potential concern might be fish swimming out of the bubble. I'm not seeing much else, but I'm no ichthyologist so maybe wait until someone more knowledgeable responds. Is there a magical force holding the bubble up (like an invisible hovering fishbowl) or is the magic just providing levitation?

Thanks for your answer! I did update that for clarity purposes as several people were commenting about it. It is not a concern because the magic 'containers' are solid.
